# How to use SSDT to maintain "changes only" for a subset of a database and not a "whole" database?

Tags: sql-server, automation, sql-server-data-tools, sql-scripts, database-deployment

Off late, I am searching the internet for a custom solution to automate SQL server database changes deployment. Can I use SSDT to just maintain changes to the database rather than creating a database project and import the entire database.?

I have 3 or 4 third party applications which have their own SQL databases. I am tasked with building an integration between these applications(essentially between these databases in real).

All I need is to write few stored procedures, functions, triggers and create few new tables to the existing database(s). Can I use SSDT for my task without importing the entire database into the database project but only starting with the changes? Any pointers on this are much appreciated!

TIA.

Comment: The 3 or 4 third party applications with their own SQL databases, how many servers are we talking? How many databases for each server? How many tables in each database? I am asking only about the tables that you need to keep track of. How many tables need essential close monitoring?

Comment: @CrazyCucumber, The set up is like this. Databases are hosted in the same server. We have Pre-Prod(which is DEV as well) and Prod. So two servers. There are approx 5 - 8 tables per database that i am interested on. As for close monitoring, i am not sure.

Comment: Irrespective of the size or load, I am looking for an automation solution..